# How to write unit test when a member function is calling another member function of the same object in golang?

Tags: go, go-testing

In golang, I often see a member function calling another member function of the same object. For example check following golang code:

```
type Obj struct{}

func (o Obj) First() {
    // do something
    o.Second()
}

func (o Obj) Second() {
    // do another thing
}
```

**How would you write unit test for function `First` ?** If you write unit test for function "First" in above code, how would you mock the function "Second" ?

To fix this, I could come up with following possibilities:

1. Function `Second()` might be responsibility of another object i.e. a dependency of `Obj`. So `Obj` have more responsibilities than it should have.
2. Pass the Object to `First()` as argument for a quick fix (which ends up forever in the code). Doesn't look good.

```
func First(o Obj) {
    // do something
    o.Second()
}
```

4. Add an Interface type as argument to `First()` which provides behaviour `Second()`

But, I've ended up in a situation where I broke down `First()` into smaller functions for the sake of readability. The `Second()` simply can't be taken out to some other object.

Comment: Would you mock the block of code that you abstracted into `Second` if you didn't abstract it in the first place? i.e. if you kept it inlined inside `First`? You probably wouldn't, would you? It's unreasonable to want to mock that block of code __just__ because you've now packaged it inside a separate method. Does every single method or function call need to be mocked? Did some "tool" claim it's good practice? What stops you from writing the test for `First` _without_ mocking `Second`?

Comment: A _unit_ is usually defined as something larger than a single method. Besides, in your tests, you should focus on behaviour, not implementation; that method `First` calls method `Second` is an implementation detail, which should have no bearing on how the test is written.

Comment: I tend to only mock my external dependencies

Comment: Would testing _each_ _line_ in isolation somehow "improve" the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why you think you should mock `Second`? (sorry for starting with a question)

When you test you should focus on observable behavior (test public interface), from the test point of view it is not important what is called behind the scenes.
If `Second` on its own does not form a dependency, does it have to be public? If it is a part of bigger feature in my opinion you should accept that, from test/user point of view it is unobservable implementation detail that you call it from `First`.